# Format number with leading point/dot in exponential in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, format, exponential

I have several variables containing numbers.

I need all of them in the style of '.xxxxxE+YY' as a string.

e.g. '250' would be '.25000E+03' with no 0 (always the '.' leading).

I tried several ways, read the Matlab help and googled and searche here but no luck so far.

Does anyone know the trick? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show us your current tries please.

Comment: That's not standard engineering notation, at least not as usually output by *printf-style functions. You'll likely need to hack something together if you really need something like this.

Comment: Do you want to manually generate strings based on that format?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the warm welcome!

Sadly, I absolutely do need it in this format as it will be read by another program just like that where already many datasets exist.

Best I did so far was sprintf('% 5.5E',250) which puts out 2.50000E+02.

If there is no function to get this format, how would I hack something like that? I'm still new to Matlab. Learning a lot (which means reading in the Matlab help and on SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. I'm assuming the numbers are positive (otherwise you'd need to deal with the minus sign separately).

```
x = 250;
e = floor(log10(x))+1;
s1 = sprintf('.%5i', round(x*10^(5-e)));
s2 = sprintf('%02d', abs(e));
s = [s1 'E' repmat('+', e>=0) repmat('-', e<0) s2];
```

The `repmat('+', e>=0) repmat('-', e<0)` part of the string is just a way to introduce a `'+'` or `'-'` sign for the exponent (one of the `repmat`s gives a single character and the other gives an empty string). Of course it could also be done with an `if`-`else` clause.

Example results:

- `250` gives `'.25000E+03'`
- `1.23456` gives `'.12346E+01'`
- `.1` gives `'.10000E+00`
- `.0123456` gives `'.12346E-01'`

Comment: Hello Luis, thank you for your suggestion. This works good but only for numbers greater than 1. I don't have negative numbers but do have numbers between 0 and 1.

1.2345 gives .12345E+01
0.1 gives .100000E+-1
1 gives .100000E+00

Comment: Sorry, the `+` in the format specifier was misplaced. Try it now

Comment: But now the exponent may have less than two figures. Working on it

Comment: Ah yeah, this is better!

I need exactly 2 digits after the E+/- so I changed it to:

`x = 250;
e = ceil(log10(x));
s = sprintf('.%5iE%+03d', round(x*10^(5-e)), e);`

However, numbers in the logarithmic line (? sorry bad english) like 0.1, 1 and 10 still have errors. The exponent is wrong and also it shows 6 digits after the dot.